# How to retrieve the raw markdown/source of a rejected suggested edit?

Tags: support, markdown, rejected-edits

I want to retrieve the raw markdown/source of a rejected suggested edit, which is the code in the text box above 'Post Your Question', i.e. the raw markdown/source, not the rendered output:

[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking but if you mean the markdown source, go to the [page for the suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2708032) and click the "markdown" tab (it's next to "rendered output", just above the post and below the review results). This applies to any suggested edit regardless of whether it is approved, rejected, or still being reviewed.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  Done. See edited OP.

Comment: @JasonC   Done. See edited OP.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is also frequently used to mean "Original *Post*". *Post* vs *poster* just depends on context. And in any case the meaning of the previous comments is very clearly understood and there's really no need for a corrective comment of any kind...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [suggested edit that got rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50533). Using the <kbd>markdown</kbd> (not the <kbd>rendered output</kbd>) button it shown 2 panes: left is what it looked like BEFORE I suggested my edit, right is what I suggested to change it to.

And here is the text input of this *rejected edit that I retrieved* (as in your question) to copy/paste (from the right pane) it in this answer here (formatted as "code" now to show the *text input* exactly as I suggested it):

```
Is there a reason why CMS sites are not folded into Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc.?

These sites seem to cover areas that are already covered more broadly by other sites...

**Note**: CMS = Content Management System - such as WordPress, etc
```

The above was a rather small post that showed the entire source. There are also cases such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50473) where it says "*X identical lines skipped*" (depending on your edit there may be multiple cases like this). That's because they are identical, so in those cases you can retrieve the relevant pieces of those skipped line from the source where you started from when you suggested your edit.

Note: credits to [Jason C](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/230261/jason-c) for the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295745/how-can-you-retrieve-the-text-input-source-of-a-rejected-suggested-edit#comment959542_295745) posted below the question, which didn't mention the "*X identical lines skipped*" though.